# Why am I getting a warning about absolute addressing with immediate operands?

Tags: macos, x86-64, nasm

This little program works fine on OS X, using nasm:

```
        global  _main
        extern  _puts
        section .text
        default rel
_main:
        push    rbp
        lea     rdi, [message]
        call    _puts
        pop     rbp
        ret
message:
        db      'Hello, world', 0
```

Here's how it runs:

```
$ nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && gcc hello.o && ./a.out
Hello, world
```

But if I replace the LEA instruction (with a memory operand) with an equivalent MOV immediate:

```
        global  _main
        extern  _puts
        section .text
        default rel
_main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rdi, message ; <---- Should have same effect as lea rdi, [message]
        call    _puts
        pop     rbp
        ret
message:
        db      'Hello, world', 0
```

The program will run but with a warning message, that I know has been asked about before on Stack Overflow:

```
$ nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && gcc hello.o && ./a.out
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from hello.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
Hello, world
```

My question is why does this warning occur? I see the error is complaining about the linker not liking **absolute addressing**; however the MOV command is clearly using an immediate operand, not an absolute address!  Is the warning mislabeled?  I'm puzzled that

As an aside, this distinction does not happen under Linux.  Removing `default rel` and the underscores on `main` and `puts` gives me a warning-free run on Ubuntu.  What is OS X doing differently here?  Is it a case of the assembler default configurations being set differently?  Or is it something weird like OS X following AMD's ABI more closely than Ubuntu?

Comment: In the `MOV` case you've got an immediate operand, whereas in the `LEA` case you've got a memory operand.

Comment: Good point! So the question was poorly worded.  Edited.